# Split and sort value in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a raw data dataframe for example:

```
      Data
0   XZ_1A-2A
1   XZ_3C
2   XZ_4B-5A
3   XZ_18A-20C
```

And I want to split (and delete `XZ_`) it to be

```
      Data        T1      T2
0   XZ_1A-2A      1A      2A
1   XZ_3C         3C
2   XZ_4B-5A      4B      5A
3   XZ_18A-20C   18A     20C
```

Then sort by number

```
       T1      T2
0      2A      1A
1      3C
2      5A      4B
3     20C     18A
```

Thanks for your help.

---

#### [fixed]

Update_1:
When input data:

```
      Data
0   XZ_17A-1A
1   XZ_5C
2   XZ_3A-28A
```

and compile with

```
df= (df['Data'].str.split('_|-',expand=True)[[1,2]]).rename(columns={1:'T2',2:'T1'}).fillna('')
asc=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['T1','T2']],axis=1)) 
des= asc[asc.columns.values[::-1]]
```

I got the output

```
     1    0
0   1A  17A
1   5C  
2   3A  28A
```

---

Update_2:
If there are more than 2 items (about 1~5) in simgle row, how to sort it?

```
       Data
0   XZ_17A-1A
1   XZ_5C
2   XZ_3A-28A
3   XZ_5A-19A-42C   
4   XZ_3A-28A-41A-42A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df= df['Data'].str.split('_|-',expand=True)[[1,2]]
```

Output:

```
     1     2
0   1A    2A
1   3C  None
2   4B    5A
3  18A   20C
```

To get sorted value use below,

```
df= (df['Data'].str.split('_|-',expand=True)[[1,2]]).rename(columns={1:'T2',2:'T1'}).fillna('')
asc= df.apply(np.sort,axis=1)
asc=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['T1','T2']],axis=1)) #alternative way
des= asc[asc.columns.values[::-1]]
print des
```

Output:

```
    T1    T2
0   2A    1A
1   3C     
2   5A    4B
3  20C   18A
```

Explanation:

a) after cleanup the data, sort the dataframe by ascending order based on row values using `np.sort,axis=1`

b) To get descending order reverse the column order.

c) use fillna to get exact result.

Edit:

```
df= (df['Data'].str.split('_|-',expand=True)[[1,2]]).rename(columns={1:'T2',2:'T1'})

df['n1']=df['T1'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
df['n2']=df['T2'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
res=pd.DataFrame()
res['result'] =df.apply(lambda x: [x['T1'],x['T2']] if x['n1']>x['n2'] else [x['T2'],x['T1']],axis=1).fillna('')
res[['T1','T2']]=res['result'].astype(str).str.replace("\[|\]|'",'').str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Output:

```
       result   T1     T2
0   [17A, 1A]  17A     1A
1  [5C, None]   5C      
2   [28A, 3A]  28A     3A
```

For multiple column see below example,

```
df= (df['Data'].str.split('_|-',expand=True)[[1,2]]).rename(columns={1:'T2',2:'T1'}).fillna('')
df['n1']=df['T1'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
df['n2']=df['T2'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
df['n3']=[432,4,15]
res=pd.DataFrame()
res['result'] =df.apply(lambda x: sorted([x['n1'],x['n2'],x['n3']],reverse=True),axis=1)
res[['T1','T2','T3']]=res['result'].astype(str).str.replace("\[|\]|'",'').str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Input:

```
    T2   T1    n1    n2   n3
0  17A   1A   1.0  17.0  432
1   5C        NaN   5.0    4
2   3A  28A  28.0   3.0   15
```

Output:

```
             result    T1     T2    T3
0  [432, 17.0, 1.0]   432   17.0   1.0
1     [nan, 5.0, 4]   nan    5.0     4
2   [28.0, 15, 3.0]  28.0     15   3.0
```

Comment: @MohamedThasinah thanks, it works. But I found there's another question: it seems only sort the first number. For example: when values are 3 and 28, i will get 3 at the first column after sorting

Comment: Sorry for another question: If I have more than 2 items in one row need to sort, then how do I change this line `res['result'] =df.apply(...`

Comment: Then you have to sort your row by descending order and store the value is same list. If I found free time I'll update that into my solution

Comment: Sorry again for another question. Is there any way to let the output of multiple column sorting be the format of number+alphabet, just like the output of two columns

Comment: @xiumpt - No you can't get, you will lose the order.

Answer (score 2):

try..

```
>>> df1
         Data
0    XZ_1A-2A
1       XZ_3C
2    XZ_4B-5A
3  XZ_18A-20C


>>> newdf = df1['Data'].str.split('_|-', expand=True)[[1,2]]
```

Use `rename` function to replace the column names as Below..

```
>>> newdf.rename(columns={1: 'T1', 2: 'T2'}, inplace=True)
>>> newdf
    T1    T2
0   1A    2A
1   3C  None
2   4B    5A
3  18A   20C
```

However, if you also want to replace the `None` into empty string then itcan be as follows:

```
>>> newdf['T2'].fillna(value='', inplace=True)
>>> newdf
    T1   T2
0   1A   2A
1   3C
2   4B   5A
3  18A  20C
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the following steps:

1. Use `.ix(num)` to get the value at the row `num`.
2. Split the value on a hyphen by using `.split('-')`
3. Add an if statement to check the number of elements in the array and create the data frame accordingly.

Hopefully, this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is :

```
df1 = data["Data"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True)
output:

      0        1
0     XZ_1A    2A
1     XZ_3C    None
2     XZ_4B    5A
3     XZ_18A   20C

df2 = df1[0].str.split("_", n = 1, expand = True) 
output : 

   0    1
0  XZ   1A
1  XZ   3C
2  XZ   4B
3  XZ  18A


data["T1"]= df2[1]
data["T2"]= df1[1]
```

Finally you got :

```
         Data   T1    T2
0    XZ_1A-2A   1A    2A
1       XZ_3C   3C  None
2    XZ_4B-5A   4B    5A
3  XZ_18A-20C  18A   20C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['XZ_17A-1A','XZ_5C','XZ_3A-28A'],columns=['a'])<br>
df1 = df['a'].str.split('_|-',expand=True).loc[:,1:2]<br>
df1[3],df1[4] = df1[1].str.extract('([0-9]*)').astype('float'),df1[2].str.extract('([0-9]*)').astype('float')<br>
df2 = df1.sort_values(by=[3,4],ascending=True,axis=0)<br>
df2.drop([3,4],axis=1,inplace=True)<br>
df2.columns=['T1','T2']
```